# Specifying number of slurm nodes

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, slurm

For a year my scheduling command with slurm was fine, but is now attempting to allocate N+1 nodes for my job now that someone else is scheduled on a node I'm running on.

I'm trying to run a job on **2** nodes that runs as 48 processes all with two cores.  (so, 48 jobs with MPI, each using `OMP_NUM_THREADS`=2), so **96** all together.

In the past I've always run this with (using `hostname` as example since it illustrates the problem)

```
srun  --partition=intel \
   -N 2                 \
   --ntasks-per-node=24 \
   --ntasks=48          \
   --cpus-per-task=2    \
   hostname
```

But now squeue is telling me that this is `pending` for `resources` awaiting **3** nodes instead of **2**.

```
$ squeue
     JOBID PARTITION    NAME     USER    ST       TIME  NODES NODELIST(REASON)
     1282   intel     hostname  gmp13x64 PD       0:00      3 (Resources)
     1229   intel     bwd-pm25   shunliu  R 5-12:51:18      1 dena5
```

The `intel` queue is composed of two nodes, `dena5` and `dena6`

```
gmp13x64@dena:script_dev$ sinfo --Node --long
Sat Nov  5 10:49:51 2016
NODELIST          NODES PARTITION       STATE CPUS    S:C:T MEMORY TMP_DISK WEIGHT FEATURES REASON              
dena5                 1     intel   allocated   48   2:12:2 128833     1951      1   (null) none                
dena6                 1     intel        idle   48   2:12:2 128833     1951      1   (null) none
```

My interpretation is the info that `sinfo` is giving is that my setup should be fine.  Plus, in the past this has always worked.

Why is slurm all of a sudden saying that this requires 3 nodes?  How would that even be allowed considering the `intel` partition only has 2 nodes?  Am I mis-interpreting some of the flags I'm using?

Comment: Can you show the output of squeue that shows it is waiting for 3 nodes?

Comment: Sure, I added the output of `squeue` above.